# Should I handle signals when I need to just perform a single task

Tags: c, linux, service, daemon, systemd

I am writing a systemd service to update the firmware on the machine, if it is not the same as present in the executable.

```
[Unit]
Description=Firmware Update Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/fwupdate

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In the code, I just call a function which will verify if the firmware needs to be updated or not and updates if necessary.

Below is the pseudo code:

```
int main()
{
    FwuRunFirmwareUpdater();
    return 0;
}
```

Should I still add the code to handle SIGTERM, am I missing anything as I am writing systemd service/daemon for the first time

Comment: In general you should handle signals if you need specific actions when the signal occurs, e.g. if you want to perform a (fast) cleanup and exit instead of your process simply being killed at any point of its unfinished task.

Comment: To confirm there is no need of creating a new process using fork in case of systemd right

Comment: What happens if you receive a SIGTERM while running the update? Is it safe to simply stop?

Comment: No, it should not stop in between, it should be atomic operation

Comment: It depends on how long the update may run. When the system (or some process) sends a SIGTERM to your process it should stop within a reasonable time. Either you can ignore SIGTERM, finish the task and exit or handle SIGTERM, clean up or revert your unfinished task and exit. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503058/what-is-the-delay-between-sigterm-and-sigkill-on-shutdown